# How to track User Live Location by using Google Maps in swift 3?

Tags: ios, google-maps, location

I am new to Swift and Google Maps can any one suggest how to track the user Live location by using Google Maps Swift 3.

Comment: Hi kishan, welcome to Stack Overflow! It is expected that you at least [attempt to do some work before asking](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several steps you need to take into account.

Overall you need to:

- Get location updates using Core Location `CLLocation`
- Initialize Google Maps View `GMSMapView`
- Every time you get an update you animate the map view to new location
- If you want to track the path use `GMSPath` and `GMSPolyline`

So...

Get location updates using Core Location:

- You'll need to import the library
- Create an instance of CLLocationManager which is the class that manages the updates
- Implement `CLLocationManagerDelegate` methods to receive each update

You can read Apple's documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation)

Initialize Google Maps View:

- You can do this by code following [Google's guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/map-with-marker)

Every time you get an update you animate the map view to new location:

- This is where the tracking takes place, each time you get an update in the delegate methods of `CLLocationManagerDelegate`, you'll get an array of `CLLocation`, you can use this to animate your map to new location.

Example (Inside delegate method):

```
...
 let newLocationCoordinate = locations.last!.coordinate
 self.mapView.animate(toLocation: newLocationCoordinate)
// mapView should be of type GMSMapView
```

If you want to track the path use `GMSPath` and `GMSPolyline`:

- To do this you will need to store an instance of both `GMSPath` and `GMSPolyline`, initialize them in viewDidLoad or in your initialization code.
- Each time you get an update you should do something like:

  ```
  // Say your GMSPath instance is called trackingPath:
  trackingPath.add(locations.last!.coordinate)
  // Say your GMSPolyline instance is called trackingPolyline:
  // You clear the mapView to remove obsolete polyline
  mapView.clear()
  // You update your polyline with the path
  trackingPolyline.path = path
  // You add the polyline to the UI by pointing its map atribute to your mapView
  trackingPolyline.map = mapView
  ```

This is a very rough overall of what you should do but I hope it gives you an idea of what steps to follow. Google's guides are very complete, you can follow them to get a better idea of how their library works. You can also use Apple's MapKit if your app is tracking users in the USA, I do not recommend Apple's MapKit for other areas. GoogleMaps has way better support for address format and street accuracy in areas outside the USA.

Can's recommendation to use a Singleton to access location is by far what you should do, if several views access location use a Singleton to optimise performance. Only one instance in your entire app should manage location updates and pass them to the views necessary.

Comment: @ Daniel soto first of all thank you for answering to my question.

Comment: Actuallyn my question is how to track user live location for example if we book any cab in uber where we can able to see driver live location.in that scenario which one i have to choose applemapkit or google map kit

Comment: Well, as I said before, the decision of using Google Maps or MapKit depends more on the country in which you will be using the app and Apple's support for that country; not on the use you will give it. The procedure of tracking is the same the difference is, in the same example you give, Uber is the one implementing location updates, when it receives one it sends it to a Backend service or to the passenger. When the passenger receives it from backend or directly, it should update the path, polyline and map accordingly, using the same procedure I showed before.

Answer (score 0):

For this task, you gonna need to integrate Google Maps SDK into your project. [This RayWenderlich tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/109888/google-maps-ios-sdk-tutorial) is a getting started about Google Maps on iOS.

But if you’re not dependent on Google Maps, that is you don’t have a specific need, do think about Apple Maps(MapKit) instead. Don’t unnecessarily integrate dependencies into your project.

You also going to need CoreLocation. This is Apple’s library for everything location related. Hence the name. :]

A while back, [I wrote](https://github.com/cansurmeli/Singleton-CLLocationManager) a singleton object to retrieve the user location project wide. With it, a single entity retrieves the location information and you can access it through out your project without duplicates. It’s a bad practice to have more than one CoreLocationManager or put it into your AppDelegate. At first, you might not get it but later it’s the way to go.